# find probability mass function of a random variable

Tags: probability

We pick two numbers randomly from the set $\{1,2,...,n \}$ without replacement. Let $X$ denote the smalles and $Y$ denote the larger one of the two numbers. Find probability mass function of $Z=Y-X$.

#### try

Each number is equally likely to occur so $P(Z = z) = \frac{1}{n}$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, the numbers that can be taken by $Z$ are not equiprobable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For $k=1,\dots,n-1$ we have:$$\{Z=k\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-k}\{X=i\wedge Y=k+i\}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct. The distribution is not uniform and we only have $n-1$ possible values.

$Z$ takes values from the set $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$. There are ${n\choose 2}$ ways to pick two numbers randomly from the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ without replacement. Hence, we have that
$$
P(Z=k)=\frac{n-k}{{n\choose 2}}
$$
for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$ since there are $n-k$ ways for $Z$ to be equal to $k$.